# In Joomla how do I iterate over a database object

Tags: php, joomla

Sorry. I am very new to Joomla.

After I load data from the database like this:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('user_id')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__user_profiles'));
$db->setQuery($query);
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

How to I show the results?

Comment: It's probably just an StdObject or an array. Do a `var_dump` and have a look see at what it is. Normal looping methods should work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result->user_id.'<br />';
}
```